# trying to write code in python that will loop through server names in a url

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

This is what i have it works when there is only 1 server name in the URL It reads from. But when there is any more than the one server name it doesn't work. so i'm trying to do a loop however it loops through each character instead of each line. Im writing this in python 2.7. any advice

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import urllib2
import subprocess
import sys

def stuff ():
    data = urllib2.urlopen('url')
    next(data)
    for line in data:
        return(line).rstrip


HOST=stuff()

COMMAND= "uname -a"

for i in HOST:

ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND],
                   shell=False,
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
if result == []:
    error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
else:
    print result
```

Comment: change `result(line).rstrip` to `yield(line).rstrip`

Comment: `return` immediately breaks out of a function, so your `for` loop can only ever do one iteration

Comment: I'm not clear why you're running subprocesses for this.

Comment: @MegaIng do you mean change     return(line).rstrip?

Comment: @roganjosh using subprocesses is the best way ive found so far to do it. im not sure how to have it loop through the function successfully multiple times